# I have a C++ openGL code to model my NAO robot as stick man

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, nao-robot

I have a C++ openGL code to model my NAO robot as stick man. My plan is to do the computation of inverse kinematics in my model and send it to NAO. But I am only familiar with programming NAO robot using .Net API( which is a C# code). Is there a way for me to send some set of points to my C++ model and read it's output from my C# code?

Comment: It depends...  C# is set up to provide inter-operable calls to programs built in C++.  If your C++ program can be implemented as a DLL, then you can interface it using C# interop.

Comment: Thank you @paddy. Let me rewrite my question as can I implement openGL C++ application as DLL?

Comment: Yes, I believe that you can use OpenGL from a DLL.  You're using Windows, right?  Just make sure you **don't do any initialisation or cleanup from the DllMain**.  That includes the loading of any DLLs, allocating data on the heap, pretty much anything.  Instead, have your DLL provide an `Initialise()` and `Shutdown()` function and require the caller to use those.